# "numbers who have" vs. "number who has"

Tags: verb-agreement

MS-Word strikes again: In the following test, it has *green underlined* the phrase "number who have" and suggested either:

- numbers who have
- number who has

Here is what I've written (slightly paraphrased for you non-statistics experts

> So if you want to find Probability that "a subject tests positive" or
>   "subject uses" by adding the column and row totals, you have counted
>   the 44 people in the top left twice. So, to get the correct number who
>   have tested positive or used drugs, you have to subtract the ones you
>   counted twice. The total number of subjects who use or have tested
>   positive is 50+134-44=140 (same number as before).

See, there's only one number: the number of people who test positive or used drugs. So clearly the first choice above is wrong.

The second choice just sounds plain wrong (but I can't put my finger on it).

Who's right? Me or MS-Word's fine grammarian?

Comment: 'The correct number _of people_' would scan much better, and might get rid of the pesky green line as well...

Comment: Thanks, @Elendi. It did get rid of the green line. But it's too wordy for me. And that isn't really how math people write (or think). The number itself is an object (albeit, an abstract one) and we dealing with numbers, regardless of whether they represent people, cars or cats, etc.

Comment: Well, if you're arbitrarily applying special rules for 'math language', why are you worried about what MS Word thinks is correct? If your goal is to reduce wordiness, just use 'To get the correct number...' rather than repeat 'tested positive or used drugs'.

Comment: Oh yeah. That works much better. :D